# Excel VBA selecting data from a sorted Table

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, rowcount

I am running into a problem in VBA in excel. 
I am trying to create a participant registration program in excel for a sports tournament. One can add data like the weight, age and name of a participant. And then based on that, The participants are divided into poules named with letters A, B... until Z. I have a table which can sort these poules by letters and then for example only display the participants which are in poule A such as below

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pimnX.png)

Now i want to count the numbers with VBA macros of participants in the poule which is displayed by the sorted table. For example when i sort on poule A it has to return 3 and when i sort on B, it has to return 2.

Determined by the number of participants in a poule the program will print a different poule scheme, depending on the number of participants. (i have this part in VBA)

The problem is when i have a sorted table like below

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFhsc.png)

It counts all the participants, and not just the ones in B or any other sorted letter.

I have this:
    Sub Count()

```
Dim nRows As Integer

nRows = Range(Range("A18"), Range("A18").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
MsgBox (nRows)

End Sub
```

This works well if you sort A, but when you sort any other letter, it counts All the table until that letter. Eg. when you sort B, it displays 5 (Number of A + B).

I have looked on the internet for a really long time to find a solution but without succes.

I hope my question is clear and that somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using worksheet functions.  Use Subtotal when working with filtered data.

These parameters evaluate all cells visible or hidden

- 1    AVERAGE
- 2    COUNT
- 3    COUNTA
- 4    MAX
- 5    MIN
- 6    PRODUCT
- 7    STDEV
- 8    STDEVP
- 9    SUM
- 10   VAR
- 11   VARP

These parameters evaluate only visible cells

- 101   AVERAGE
- 102   COUNT
- 103   COUNTA
- 104   MAX
- 105   MIN
- 106   PRODUCT
- 107   STDEV
- 108   STDEVP
- 109   SUM
- 110   VAR
- 111   VARP

Comment: No i am using VBA functions, in order to count the participants in a poule and depending on that the VBA code, prints the corresponding poule scheme

Comment: Thank you for your answer though! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Range.SpecialCells will return a range of only visible cells.

```
Dim rSource As Range
Dim rVisibleCells

Set rSource = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set rVisibleCells = rSource.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

MsgBox rVisibleCells.Rows.Count
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer,

Comment: The code does work now, except that it only counts the first letters it encounters. 
So when the first column for the poules is for example A A A E A A B B E.
And i sort to A and use the count function, it only returns a value of 3 and not of 5 (because there are 5 A's)

When I sort the table to A, it looks like this (column number, poule value): 
14 A
15 A
16 A
18 A
19 A

And it returns just 3, have you maybe got any fixes for that problem as well?

Comment: Do you want to filter the list?  Or do you want a filtered array?

Comment: I want to filter the list, and then return a count of the size of the poules, i added a comment to my question with a pic of the problem

Comment: I don't understand you?

Comment: The range was starting at A18.  I fixed it to start at A2.  Let me know if this fixes it.

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry I missed it to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The code does work now, except that it only counts the first letters it encounters. 
So when the first column for the poules is for example A A A E A A B B E.
And i sort to A and use the count function, it only returns a value of 3 and not of 5 (because there are 5 A's)

When I sort the table to A, it looks like this (column number, poule value):

14 A

15 A

16 A

18 A

19 A

And it returns just a count of 3, have you maybe got any fixes for that problem as well?

Pictures:

[sorted tabel to E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGNKD.png)

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfuf1.png)